# Is there salesforce health cloud certification?

Tags: health-cloud

Is there a salesforce health cloud certification?  I did some looking online and I don't think so, but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

As on today, there are no certifications available on Health Cloud.

To get all list of certifications, refer [Salesforce certifications](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/administratoroverview)